# Where to download titanium studio?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have been developing with Titanium Studio for some time at the start of the year, and would now after a longer break get back into it again. I've tried to find a place to download the latest version, but for some reason i can only find old releases.

On the Appcelerator website i can see that there is still a description on how to download and install Titanium Studio, but the download page doesn't offer the actual download anymore: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Downloading_and_Installing_Studio-section-30083017_DownloadingandInstallingStudio-InstallingTitaniumStudio

As i understand i can also use Appcelerator Studio offers the same features, plus more. But i don't really need these additional features, as they seem to be mainly related to the Appcelerator Platform.

Is Titanium Studio still supported? If yes, where do i get it from?

Comment: Use the Appcelerator Studio instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot has changed since you last used Titanium. They introduced a whole new platform.

If you used Titanium before April 1st, you qualified for a free indie seat, but you should've redeemed it by now. There still is the open source variant, but you need to use your editor for that. I personally don't know exactly how that works.

When using the Indie seat, you can download Appcelerator Studio, and the latest SDK's.

You can develop apps for free, but when you want to deploy them to production you will need an indie seat (at least) when using the platform, or you can dive into the open source variant.

Any questions can also be asked at http://tislack.org, a slack community with about 450 Titanium Developers (and counting).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot use Titanium Studio any more. My version stopped working as they changed to Appcelerator studio this summer. If you have been using Titanium Studio earlier I think you qualify for an "Indie seat" which gives you some more facilities (and you do want to claim that). Have a look at appcelerator.com and send an email to them.

/John